# How to autocomplete or use abbreviations in bash command

Tags: bash, vim, autocomplete, placeholder, scp

Everyday I have to transfer files to many (6) AWS EC2 instances via **SCP**,  from my bash terminal,  on Linux Debian 8.  I have to hand write:

```
i) files to transfer;  

ii) destination folder;  

iii) url to my .pem certificate;   

iv)  openning urls on the servers: ec2-user@XX.XX.XXX....
```

As a lazy programmer I want to use some kind of abbreviation in order to type less, having in mind that iii) and iv) are the same generally.

First I wrote a bash script which asks me for files to be transferred and folder on my server, however it takes more time due to the fact that prompts for an answer every time I transfer.  Instead,  I can just use arrow to repeat the bash command previously introduced.

Here is an example of the current command I use to run:

```
scp -i /pem/aws.pem file_to_upload.txt ec2-user@XX-XX-XX-XX.amazonwas.com:/var/www/html/folder/
```

the following strings require repeated typing:

```
scp -i /pem/aws.pem
ec2-user@.....  // this is a large string of 64 characters.
```

I'd love some sort of placeholder, where I just type the path to files to upload and the remote folder.

How can I autocomplete or use abbreviations,  like **VIM** to insert the same recurrent text in a bash command?

Comment: Can you give **specific** examples of the commands you need to run and what parts are duplicates? A shell function sounds like it might work here.

Comment: Just updated my question and wrote an explicit command,

Comment: No parts of that command are duplicated within the command itself. So this is a cross-command duplication? What parts of that command are unique to that run and which parts are common to all runs of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the solutions already posted work, but they are really ugly and not the way how it should be. Remember, we still have `~/.ssh/config`?

```
scp -i /pem/aws.pem file_to_upload.txt ec2-user@XX-XX-XX-XX.amazonwas.com:/var/www/html/folder/
```

will boil down to

```
scp file_to_upload.txt am:/var/www/html/folder/
```

if you set up your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host am:
  Hostname XX-XX-XX-XX.amazonwas.com
  User ec2-user
  IdentityFile /pem/aws.pem
```

There your local file gets auto-completed and remote directory also if you don't use passphrase (or set up `ControlMaster` and `ControlPersist` options - this will even be fast!).

Comment: your answer guided me to find the best solution.  Finally have to type something like "scp file,txt remote:${folder}".  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could take advantage of using some bash aliases in your bashrc or bash_profile.

[Take a look at my .bashrc file on githut](https://github.com/AJ-Acevedo/dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc#L42)

I often need to know what is my ip address. One example of a bash alias is my showip alias.

```
alias showip='ifconfig | grep "inet" | grep -v 127.0.0.1'
```

I have also created aliases to ssh into my Linux boxes. You could create a bash alias that should solve your problem.

Copying directory recursively from host:

```
scp -r user@host:/directory/SourceFolder TargetFolder
```

NOTE: If the host is using a port other than port 22, you can specify it with the -P option:

```
scp -P 2222 user@host:/directory/SourceFile TargetFile
```

Comment: I use aliases, indeed I use when need to ssh connect to my boxes,  but aliases are fixed.  Just stamp the commend and execute,  I need placeholders to define which files to what folder will be transferred,  but I pointed a bash script is slower due to prompts requesting data.

Answer (score 0):

When you are connecting to your bash terminal with a ssh program, see what keyboard mappings your ssh supports.
Other options, based on

```
echo "This is a line I do not want to type twice"
```

Look how you can use the bash history

```
!!
^twice^two times^
```

You can put your abbreviations in shell variables

```
no2="This is a line I do not want to type twice"
echo "${no2}"
```

And you can use an alias

```
my2='echo "This is a line I do not want to type twice"'
my2
```

The shell variables and aliases can be put in `${HOME}/.bashrc`.

Comment: I know and regularly use aliases, to ssh connect.  However aliases just stamp and execute the recorded string.  Using abbreviations is new for me and I think that a mix of abbreviations and placeholders can solve the problem.

Comment: Another possibility that I do not like is defining your own function (in .bashrc) like `function mycp` and translate the parameters $1 and $2 with something like `file1=$(grep "^$1=" $HOME/abbrev.txt|cut -d"=" -f2-)`. abbrev.txt must have lines like `short=this_is_not_a_short_filename_that_can_be called_with_short`.

Comment: I solved the issu with a mix of both accepted answrs, using ssh_config and shell abbreviations.  Great!